# Why is the agen-server required to run in jmeter if I use the exec?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using [jmeter perfom plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for oberving cpu usage and others. Unfortunately the required serveragent fails if I ask for some metrics. So I used the `EXEC` Metric to collect the data, which will run a script I wrote. This works, until I stop the serveragent.

Questions:
Why is the serveragent required to run, even if i am executing scripts?
Are the scripts executed in the agentserver?

Answer (score 1):

The [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics) consists of 2 parts:

1. [PerfMon Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) which needs to be up and running on the system under test side
2. [PerfMon Metrics Collector Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) which periodically runs a special command. gets the result and stores it in .csv file and/or plots it to the chart

So when you configure the PerfMon Metrics Collector to get CPU usage the following happens:

1. JMeter sends a command line like `metrics-single:cpu` via TCP or UDP protocol to the Server Agent
2. Server Agent translates the metric request into a [SIGAR](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar) library call
3. SIGAR translates the call into operating system function call and asks the underlying operating system for the data
4. Operating system responds with the metric value
5. SIGAR reports the metric value back to the Server Agent
6. Server Agent reports the metric value back to JMeter listener

If you won't have the Server Agent running you won't get any metrics and you won't be able to execute commands like EXEC or TAIL or whatever as finally the command is being executed on the system under test side, from JMeter you 're sending the command and waiting for the results.

If the system under test has OpenSSH server installed you could consider using [SSHMon Samples Collector](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon) instead, it doesn't require installation of any software.

Comment: for me its logical that the agent must run for metrics like cpu and memory. but if i use the exec metric is the script I provided inside the agent or the machine were jmeter is running?

Comment: i like the ida of the sshmon samples collector and will give it a try.